# Laravel : How to pass variable in web.php to blade views name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

This is my web.php file :

```
<?php $current_language = app()->getLocale();
Route::get('/',function(){ return view('fr/accueil');});
Route::get('/test',function(){ return view('{$current_language}/test');});
```

but the current_language variable is not recognized by Laravel, it says that "View [{$current_language}.test] not found.", However, I have fr/test and ar/test blade views. How, Can I pass the value of $current_language? 
Thanks, a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `use` key word to define the `$current_language` inside the anonymous function :

```
<?php $current_language = app()->getLocale();
Route::get('/',function(){ return view('fr/accueil');});
Route::get('/test',function() use($current_language){ 
    return view($current_language.'/test');
});
```

---

To get the last value of the language you shoud add the `app()->getLocale()` because the first implementation will return the first value assigned to the `$current_language` variable so you can do it like this :

```
Route::get('/test',function(){ 
    return view(app()->getLocale().'/test');
});
```

Comment: Hi , thank you a lot , It worked but It doesn't show what I expected to view, $current_language value don't change after I change language, I don't know why. in the return view($current_language.'/test'); it still fr even if the language is in arabic.

Comment: Try to do `app()->getLocale()` inside the clousure of the route like this `return view(app()->getLocale().'/test');`

Comment: Maraboc you are a genius ! Thanks a lot it worked perfectly <3

Comment: Happy to help :)